# Time Complexity of Straight Forward Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra

I am having a hard time seeing the O(mn) bound for the straightforward implementation Dijkstra's algorithm (without a heap). In my implementation and others I have found the main loop iterates n-1 times (for each vertex that is not source, n-1), then in each iteration finding the minimum vertex is O(n) (examining each vertex in the queue and finding min distance to source) and then each discovered minimum vertex would have at most n-1 neighbors, so updating all neighbors is O(n). This would seem to me to lead to a bound of O(n^2). My implementation is provided below

```
public int[] dijkstra(int s) {
      int[] dist = new int[vNum];
      LinkedList queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < vNum; i++) {
         queue.add(i); // add all vertices to the queue
         dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // set all initial shortest paths to max INT value
      }
      dist[s] = 0; // the source is 0 away from itself

      while (!queue.isEmpty()) { // iterates over n - 1 vertices, O(n)

         int minV = getMinDist(queue, dist); // get vertex with minimum distance from source, O(n)
         queue.remove(Integer.valueOf(minV)); // remove Integer object, not position at integer

         for (int neighbor : adjList[minV]) { // O(n), max n edges
            int shortestPath = dist[minV] + edgeLenghts[minV][neighbor];
            if (shortestPath < dist[neighbor]) {
               dist[neighbor] = shortestPath; // a new shortest path have been found
            }
         }
      }

      return dist;

   }
```

I don't think this is correct, but I am having trouble see where m factors in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation indeed removes the M factor, at least if we consider only simple graphs (no multiple edges between two vertices). It is O(N^2)! The complexity would be O(N*M) if you would iterate through all the possible edges instead of vertices.

EDIT: Well, it is actually O(M + N^2) to be more specific. Changing value in some vertex takes O(1) time in your algorithm and it might happen each time you consider an edge, in other words, M times. That's why there is M in the complexity.

Unfortunately, if you want to use simple heap, the complexity is going to be O(M* log M) (or M log N). Why? You are not able to quickly change values in heap. So if dist[v] suddenly decreases, because you've found a new, better path to v, you can't just change it in the heap, because you don't really know it's location. You may put a duplicate of v in your heap, but the size of the heap would be then O(M). Even if you store the location and update it cleverly, you might have O(N) items in the heap, but you still have to update the heap after each change, which takes O(size of heap). You may change the value up to O(M) times, what gives you O(M* log M (or N)) complexity